# Java API for MPEG TS

Tags: java, mpeg, transport

Is there any API in Java for MPEG-TS?

I need API, by which I can get parsed TS packets with information and all other information like PAT, PMT, CAT etc etc... with which I can develop my TS multiplexer application by selecting few programs from received TS.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share more info about the solution? (specially for android!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can use stream reader class and parse it into mpeg-ts. by reader i mean u need to read and store the binary from stream and output in into different format u desire.

Comment: Please explain more about your solution. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

try http://project-x.sourceforge.net/

Copied from their homepage:

European digital radio & television uses the DVB standard to broadcast its data. Project-X gives you a look behind the transmissions and tries its best to handle & repair many stream types and shows what went wrong on reception. It's not meant for a regular use but for test and learning conditions.